# Forms Authentication keeps enabling itself

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have an MVC3 .Net application that which IIS Site Forms Authentication option keeps enabling by itself. Am I missing a step in order to set it correctly, or I should just blame another member of my team?

I added a screenshot of the property I'm talking about. What I get is that the application keeps redirecting me to the login page when it is supposed to just let me in with my AC credentials. It is an internal app.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "IIS Site Forms Authentication option keeps enabling itself"? What configuration are you using and what symptoms do you see? For example, if you have enabled Integrated Authentication, but the user attempts to connect across the Internet, you can expect IIS to present a pop-up dialogue as NTLM credentials won't be propogated.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the property.

Comment: Are you overwriting the web.config file everytime you update your website ?

Comment: hum! I am. Now that I think about it. It re enables after I deploy it again. Doing